# How does libdl work with linker in android?

Tags: android, linker, shared-libraries, android-source, loader

As we know, the `/system/bin/linker` is responsible for the dynamic linking mechanism, but `libdl` have stubs for functions that are actually defined in the dynamic linker (`dlfcn.c`), and hijacked at runtime, like below:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
/* These are stubs for functions that are actually defined
 * in the dynamic linker (dlfcn.c), and hijacked at runtime.
 */
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag) { return 0; }
const char *dlerror(void) { return 0; }
void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol) { return 0; }
int dladdr(const void *addr, Dl_info *info) { return 0; }
int dlclose(void *handle) { return 0; }

void android_update_LD_LIBRARY_PATH(const char* ld_library_path) { }

#if defined(__arm__)

void *dl_unwind_find_exidx(void *pc, int *pcount) { return 0; }

#elif defined(__i386__) || defined(__mips__)

/* we munge the cb definition so we don't have to include any headers here.
 * It won't affect anything since these are just symbols anyway */
int dl_iterate_phdr(int (*cb)(void *info, void *size, void *data), void *data) { return 0; }

#else
#error Unsupported architecture. Only mips, arm and x86 are supported.
#endif
```

So when and how the hijack happen? It would be very appreciated if you can show me the code in android open source.

Answer (score 9):

From your question it isn't clear which Android version you are interested in, but it seems you are looking at an older Android version (given that it uses `dlfcn.c` instead of `dlfcn.cpp`). I will discuss the hijacking process based on Android 6.

For newer Android versions, the process is fundamentally the same, but some method names and file names have changed.

In [`bionic/README.md`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/README.md#libdl_libdl_so), the following description can be found:

> libdl/ --- libdl.so
>
> The dynamic linker interface library. This is actually just a bunch of stubs
>   that the dynamic linker replaces with pointers to its own implementation at
>   runtime. This is where stuff like `dlopen(3)` lives.
>
> linker/ --- /system/bin/linker and /system/bin/linker64
>
> The dynamic linker. When you run a dynamically-linked executable, its ELF file
>   has a `DT_INTERP` entry that says "use the following program to start me".  On
>   Android, that's either `linker` or `linker64` (depending on whether it's a
>   32-bit or 64-bit executable). It's responsible for loading the ELF executable
>   into memory and resolving references to symbols (so that when your code tries to
>   jump to `fopen(3)`, say, it lands in the right place).

The code you posted can be found in [`bionic/libdl/libdl.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/libdl/libdl.c#23):

```
// These are stubs for functions that are actually defined
// in the dynamic linker and hijacked at runtime.
void* dlopen(const char* filename __unused, int flag __unused) { return 0; }
```

We can verify the statement about the interpretation entry in the ELF binary:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.interp system/bin/vold 

String dump of section '.interp':
  [     0]  /system/bin/linker64
```

The high-level entry point for `linker` and `linker64` can be found in [`bionic/linker/linker.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#3354) (for the assembly-level entry point you would have to dig through the architecture-specific files, e.g. [`bionic/linker/arch/x86_64/begin.S`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/arch/x86_64/begin.S#33)):

```
/*
 * This is the entry point for the linker, called from begin.S. This
 * method is responsible for fixing the linker's own relocations, and
 * then calling __linker_init_post_relocation().
 */
extern "C" ElfW(Addr) __linker_init(void* raw_args) {
```

This `__linker_init` function initializes, among other things, the global variable [`static soinfo* solist;`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#73) with [`solist = get_libdl_info();`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#3408).

The `struct soinfo` is defined in [`bionic/linker/linker.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.h#172) and represents a node in a linked list (by having a member [`soinfo* next;`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.h#197)). Each node in such a linked list holds information about a shared object, including a symbol table, through the member [`symtab_`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.h#202).

The [`get_libdl_info`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/dlfcn.cpp#255) returns a linked list with a single entry, representing the `libdl.so` shared object. However, the symbol table of this node is not initialized with pointers to the stub functions from `libdl.so`, but with the real implementations: The `symtab_` member is initialized with [`__libdl_info->symtab_ = g_libdl_symtab;`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/dlfcn.cpp#260). The `g_libdl_symtab` table is initialized [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/dlfcn.cpp#211) with pointers to the real [`dlopen`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/dlfcn.cpp#84) etc.

So we found the point where the hijacking happens: The linker initializes a list of shared object information, containing as the first element an entry for `libdl.so`, with the symbol table directing to the real implementation of `dlopen` etc., instead of the stubs. The remainder of this section is about how this linked list is used to understand why this hijacking is effective.

The `__linker_init` returns the address of [`__linker_init_post_relocation`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#3133) to the calling assembly code, which jumps to this method next (e.g. in [`bionic/linker/arch/x86_64/begin.S`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/arch/x86_64/begin.S#36)).

In `__linker_init_post_relocation`, an `soinfo` struct is initialized, with `argv[0]` being the binary to be executed:

```
  soinfo* si = soinfo_alloc(args.argv[0], nullptr, 0, RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

For this `soinfo`, it will then call:

```
  if (!si->prelink_image()) {
```

The [`prelink_image`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#2490) function extracts, among other things, the pointer to the `dynamic` table of the binary:

```
bool soinfo::prelink_image() {
  /* Extract dynamic section */
  ElfW(Word) dynamic_flags = 0;
  phdr_table_get_dynamic_section(phdr, phnum, load_bias, &dynamic, &dynamic_flags);
```

The `dynamic` table can be inspected from the command line with:

```
$ readelf -d system/bin/vold

Dynamic section at offset 0x781a0 contains 46 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libbase.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
...
```

With the pointer to the `dynamic` table initialized, the [`for_each_dt_needed`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#1316) helper function becomes usable, which runs a specified action for each `NEEDED` entry in the `dynamic` table. Back in `__linker_init_post_relocation`, this helper function is used to collect the names of the shared libraries we have to load:

```
  for_each_dt_needed(si, [&](const char* name) {
    needed_library_name_list.push_back(name);
    ++needed_libraries_count;
  });
```

Next, the list of needed libraries is passed to [`find_libraries`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#1428). There, a `LoadTask` is created for each library:

```
  // Step 0: prepare.
  LoadTaskList load_tasks;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < library_names_count; ++i) {
    const char* name = library_names[i];
    load_tasks.push_back(LoadTask::create(name, start_with));
  }
```

For each such load task, it will then load the binary, and append the dependencies of the loaded library to the end of the `load_tasks` list. In other words, it does a [Breadth-first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of the dependency graph.

```
  // Step 1: load and pre-link all DT_NEEDED libraries in breadth first order.
  for (LoadTask::unique_ptr task(load_tasks.pop_front());
      task.get() != nullptr; task.reset(load_tasks.pop_front())) {
```

For each such load task, it calls [`find_library_internal`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#1383) to do the actual loading. This function first calls [`find_loaded_library_by_soname`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#1350), to check if the library has already been loaded, by traversing the global `solist`:

```
  for (soinfo* si = solist; si != nullptr; si = si->next) {
    const char* soname = si->get_soname();
    if (soname != nullptr && (strcmp(name, soname) == 0)) {
```

This is exactly the `solist` that was filled initially with the hijacked entry for `libdl.so`, pointing the non-stub implementation for `dlopen` etc. Thus, whenever a binary has `libdl.so` in the `NEEDED` list of its `dynamic` section, the loading process will always find that `libdl.so` has already been loaded and return the hijacked `soinfo`.

If a library is not found in the `solist`, the `find_library_internal` function calls `load_library` for reading the actual library file. It creates a new `soinfo` entry for this library and appends it to the end of the global `solist` using [`soinfo_alloc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/marshmallow-dev/linker/linker.cpp#228) (using the `sonext` global variable which always points to the end of the list started by `solist`).